# Resize ext4 Partition to >2TB without data loss

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, raid, ext4, resize

Is it possible to resize an ext4 partition to >2TB without data loss?

I added 1TB disk from a RAID 5 Hardware RAID (from 2TB usable to 3TB usable)

`fdisk` command output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.5 GB, 3000512503808 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364791 cylinders, total 5860375984 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd625ec35

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Note: I already tried deleting partition, resizing but still device shows 2TB, then I read about the 2TB limit.

Thanks

Comment: It might be possible but you will have to create a GPT partitions on your disk using tools such as `gparted`or `parted`.

Comment: I read about using parted via command line but when I invoke command: mklabel gpt. Warning appears: Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdb will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?

Comment: What is the size of your current partition?  Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question?

Comment: Do you currently have GPT? Make sure the partition is unmounted before partitioning. It is better to use gparted's GUI if it helps.

Comment: If you don't have GPT, then better get a backup.

Comment: Last question, If I have 3 1TB disks (Hardware RAID 5, usable is 2TB) - then I create GPT Partition on it. And if I add 1 more 1 TB disk (usable will be 3TB), I can easily resize my partition to 3TB. And I can add more in the future without the 2TB limit?

Comment: Have you truncated your `fdisk` output? It currently shows no partitions. If you have existing partitions and if your disk currently uses the MBR partition table, you can convert it from MBR to GPT using `gdisk` -- see http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html for details. As psusi says, you may need to change boot modes or re-install your boot loader. As to future expansion, that's possible, but you may need to move the backup partition data if you add space to your RAID. IIRC, `parted` does that semi-automatically. `gdisk` does it via an explicit command.

Comment: Hi Rod, I only have one partition for that disk and deleted it since I was planning to resize it. To re-size, I had to delete the partition, re-create then run resize2fs, hence, found out about the 2TB problem.

Comment: To add, I have two RAID 5 Logical drive in that server. The first raid 5 already has the OS and everything. I just need to have this second raid be more than 2TB so I can expand my LVM partition from the 1st RAID to this second RAID. It is okay for me to reformat the second RAID again and convert it to GPT. Will there be any conflicts?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your partitions are using the MBR table format, which has a 2 TB limit. If you convert to a GPT format, you can have larger partitions.

The good news is that you don't have to reformat/restore your drive to convert your drive from MBR to GPT. There is a tool called [`gdisk`](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) which can handle the conversion for you.

[`sgdisk`](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk.html) is a non-interactive version of `gdisk`, and you can check whether the conversion is possible by first running `sgisk -p /dev/sda` (assuming `sda` is the device you want to resize). Then you can run the MBR -> GPT conversion by running `sgdisk -g /dev/sda`. See the above link for the `sgdisk` docs.

Backups are highly recommended, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your partition table, not ext4.  You'll need to backup, format, and restore to convert from MBR to GPT.  Booting from GPT requires either an EFI system partition ( if your motherboard supports UEFI ) or a 1 mb bios_grub partition.  After that, resizing in the future is done easily with gparted.

Comment: As long as the start of the partiton is on the same place, the file system doesn't really care about the partition table. It's dangerous, but often very possible to change partition without any real impact - as long as the partition itself is intact.